# How to retrieve file from folder on on another subdomain without using full url

Tags: get, include

I have a file "area1.mysite.com/gallery/settings.php" that I need to include in "area2.mysite.com/index.php".  The issue is that I cannot use the full url I need to go backwards from /area2/www/index.php to /area1/www/gallery/setting.php... Does that make scents?

Comment: You should access your include by file path, not url.  Do your two domains live in the same hosting environment? In different folders on the same server?  If so, this should be possible.

Comment: Yes they are in the same environment and server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely this could be done using relative links? so you would include

```
../../../area1/www/gallery/setting.php
```

As long as that is your correct file setup in the question... But yeah basically each ../ moves you up one folder, and then you can dive back down just like you would with a non-relative link